# Using Native tensorflow RNNLayer with dropout within keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have a model implemented in Keras, but I need to implement the same model in tensorflow. So, I am looking to implement only the RNN layer of the model and keep the rest the same, that is, the prediction method, fitting the model... are all implemented in keras. Therefore, here is the code:

Keras model:

```
def emotion_model(max_seq_len, num_features, learning_rate, num_units_1, num_units_2, bidirectional, dropout, num_targets):
    # Input layer
    inputs = Input(shape=(max_seq_len, num_features))

    # 1st layer
    net = LSTM(num_units_1, return_sequences=True, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=dropout)(net)

    # 2nd layer
    net = LSTM(num_units_2, return_sequences=True, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=dropout)(net)

    # Output layer
    outputs = []
    out1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(net)  # linear activation
    outputs.append(out1)
    if num_targets >= 2:
        out2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(net)  # linear activation
        outputs.append(out2)
    if num_targets == 3:
        out3 = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(net)  # linear activation
        outputs.append(out3)

    # Create and compile model
    rmsprop = RMSprop(lr=learning_rate)
    model   = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer=rmsprop, loss=ccc_loss)  # CCC-based loss function
    return model
```

Now, I would like to replace the LSTM layers above with the equivalent code in tensorflow. Therefore, in a different Module I have implemented the following:

```
def baseline_model(inputs, cell_Size1, cell_Size2, dropout):
    with tf.variable_scope('model', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        cell1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(cell_Size1)
        cell1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell1, input_keep_prob=1.0 - dropout, state_keep_prob=1.0 - dropout)

        cell2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(cell_Size2)
        cell2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell2, input_keep_prob=1.0 - dropout, state_keep_prob=1.0 - dropout)

        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell1, cell2], state_is_tuple=True)

        # output1: shape=[1, time_steps, 32]
        output, new_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

        return output
```

I have tried `net = Lambda(partial(baseline_model, dropout))(net)` where I removed the `cell_size1` and `cell_size2` from the method "baseline_model" arguments, yet didn't work

Second, I have tried dumping directly the LSTM layers implemented in tensorflow instead of the `LSTM` layers in keras above, and this doesn't solve my problem.

Any help is much appreciated!!